# Is Christianity.SE suitable for seeking annotated bibliographical list for further research?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I posted [a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/73845/what-does-catholicism-teach-on-how-god-rewards-believers-beyond-the-promise-of-e) which understandably attracted "hold" vote for either too broad, attracted "listy" answer, or too TL;DR.  I'm new to posting questions to this site, and I'm asking long time members & moderators here on how I can form better questions that add value to the site as well as serving my own need :-).

I have modified the question (*now at rev #13*) based on the input provided by curiousdannii, Ken Graham, Peter Turner (thank you!).  But to protect the integrity of the question, it remains necessarily long and the answer demanded will likely be still complex.  So I specifically requested for an annotated bibliography format, which I used to see in entries such as the scholarly [IVP Dictionary series](https://www.logos.com/product/37742/ivp-bible-dictionary-series-8-volumes) (*see sample pages there*).

My question at this meta site is therefore:

1. Is the topic of my question suitable?
2. Does the question (*as of rev 13*) already have the right form?
3. Can I expect an answer in the form of annotated bibliography list? (of course I don't expect the scholarly level of IVP Dictionaries, but simply the format)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this would probably be too much to ask for here, and for most topics there probably isn't the expertise or people willing to put in the energy.

Instead I think it would be better to simply make a reference request question for Catholic scholars who have written about the rewards Christians receive beyond salvation. I'd expect you'd be able to receive a few answers for that, and then you can consult the bibliography in the books they recommend for more books and so on.

I think this is a better question to ask here because it doesn't require lots of original research, nor does it limit answers to those who are truly experts in the topic. Someone may have only read one book on the topic, but they could still give a useful answer which allows you and others to learn more on the topic and find further resources to study later. Such a question could also be considerably more concise.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion makes a lot of sense given the usage pattern of the community members.  Thanks for responding.